# Router in backbone doesnot work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm sure that `jquery`, `underscore` and `backbone` in my `main.js` are working with `require.js`. Here my router :

```
define([
 'jquery',
 'underscore',
 'backbone',
 'views/CartList'
], function($, _, Backbone,CartList){
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "showCart" : "cartlist"
    }
});
// Initiate the router
var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app_router.on('cartlist', function(){
        alert(1);
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
};
return {
    initialize: initialize
};
});
```

Here app.js :

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "router"], function($, Backbone, Router) {
  var initialize = function(){
    Router.initialize();
  }
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

When I browse `www.mysite.com/#showCart`, It didnot show the `alert`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `route:` prefix

```
app_router.on('route:cartlist', function () {
  alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Oh that was my bad typo, I tried like your answer. But `alert` did not work :/

Comment: Have you executed `initialize` method that module returns?

Comment: I called it in `app.js`, please have a look at `app.js` above,thanks.

Comment: You have a method that calls it but this method is not called. You have to execute initialize method that app.js returns as well